# How can I appear data from a table, using data-binding? (angularJS)

Tags: json, angularjs, data-binding

I am working on a project using spring and angularJS.I am trying to view the data of a table on UI.
My problem is that I have array inside the array.So,I would like to binding data using angularJS . I have an array inside my output as the above example:

GET request:
{
id:"1",
fullName:"Name",
courses: [{
id:1,
title:"test"
}]}
}

If i use the {{customer.courses}} I get in my table this : {id:1, title:"test"}
But I would like to view only the title?

```
 <tr ng-repeat="customer in customers">
            <td>{{ customer.fullname}}</td>->fullName 
            <td>{{ customer.courses}}</td>->{id:1, title:"test"}
<tr>
```

I am trying making another ng-repeat =course in courses. But as a result I get all the title at each customer. How can I get the customer's course in order to view the data correctly?

I try also  customer.courses[0] this but the result is the same and also  customer.courses[1] but nothing appears...

Comment: Could you provide an exemple of the table you want

Comment: I want only the title of the course. 
I have one table courses and one table customers. The table customers have all the courses that customer has registered. 
I would like to appear only the title of the course.Now I get : 
Name | Title of Course 
Ray Ca | {id:1, title: Maths}

But I want
Name     | Course
Ray           title 

I

Answer (score 0):

If you want something like that :

FullName | Course1|  Course 2

You can do :

```html
<tr ng-repeat="customer in customers">
            <td>{{ customer.fullname}}</td>
            <td ng-repeat="course in customer.courses">{{course}}</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: it doesn't appeat nothing this...thank you for your answer

Comment: <td>       
      {{customer.course[0].id}}{{customer.course[0].title}}
      {{customer.course[1].id}}{{customer.course[1].title}}
     </td> 

This works! But if customer has a lot of courses?

Comment: You can add à span in your td an add an ng-repeat on the span and iterate on your list of course